# Nodejs middleware in two files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I have these two files, and trying to call index.js from server.js which works fine and is printing 'on the other side of the code' but it is not going inside the `app.get` function. Please advise what I am doing wrong

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express")

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()

var routes = require('./api/index.js')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/t', require('./api/index')(app))

var server = app.listen(PORT, function (){
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log('Middle ware started on address http://%s:%s',host,port)
})
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')

module.exports = function(app) {
    console.log('we are in other part of code')
    app.get('/',function(req,res){
       console.log('we are there')
       console.log(res)
    })
}
```

Comment: you need to cal the url from browser or any client devices

Comment: yes I am using postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use express [Router class](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) to create modular route handlers:

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express")

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()

var routes = require('./api/index.js')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/t', routes)

app.listen(PORT, function (){
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log('Middle ware started on address http://%s:%s',host,port)
})
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('we are there')
    res.send('successfully get /t')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: we  I try to 'var routes = require('./api/index.js')(app)'  pass (app) this gives me error, when I use it without app, this works but hangs

Comment: Thanks this works, but when I do `router.get('/t,function(req,res){..}), this gives me error that `cannot GET /t` but with only `/' works fine

Comment: `app.use('/t', routes)` means that any routes inside the `routes` module will be preceded by `/t`, for example if you create a route handler to `/example/route` inside `routes` module, then you have to call it using `/t/example/route`, in your case `/t/t` is the correct route

Comment: If my answer works for you, consider accepting it for future readers

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not right try this way

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express")

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/t', require('./api/index.js'));

var server = app.listen(PORT, function (){
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log('Middle ware started on address http://%s:%s',host,port)
})
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
router=express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req,res){
      console.log('we are there')
       console.log(res)
       res.send('success')

});
module.exports=router;
```

Comment: we are in other part of code
/Users/xxx/xxx/xx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Comment: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Comment: at Function.use (/Users/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx.xx/xx/xx/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx.xx/xx/xx/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)

Comment: at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/Users/xxx/xx/xx/src/xx.xx/xx/xx/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx.xx/xx/xx/server.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)

Comment: I think you are just copy past my answer, it was my idea to use `router=express.Router();` your first answer was passing the `app` variable to `index` module using `app.use('/t', require('./api/index')(app))`

Comment: @YouneL  Dude, I just tried both options and gave him better one. And copy paste is not my job :) of course you might have given same answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express") 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser") 
const app = express()

var routes = require('./api/index.js')(app)  // Pass the app

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/t', routes)  // change this to routes

var server = app.listen(PORT, function (){  var host = server.address().address  var port = server.address().port

console.log('Middle ware started on address http://%s:%s',host,port) })
```

**index.js**

```
  const express = require('express')
  module.exports = function(app) {  
    console.log('we are in other part of code') 
    app.get('/',function(req,res){  
      console.log('we are there') 
      console.log(res)
      res.json({success : true});
    })
  }
```

Comment: It is same nothing happening, I am sending request using postman , and its waiting and waiting

Comment: that is because you are not sending any response in app.get. try res.send or res.json in app.get route